# Compile XeLaTeX tex file with latexmk

Tags: latex, latexmk, xelatex

How can one compile a `XeLaTeX` tex document using `latexmk` on Mac OS X?

At present I am running `latexmk job.tex` and getting an error:

```
! 
 ********************************************
 * XeTeX is required to compile this document.
 * Sorry!
 ********************************************.
\RequireXeTeX ...********************************}
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
l.18 \RequireXeTeX

? ^D
! Emergency stop.
\RequireXeTeX ...********************************}
                                                  \endgroup \fi 
l.18 \RequireXeTeX
```

The first line of my tex file is (as suggested by [this post](http://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/macosx-tex/2007-February/028848.html)):

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
```

and I've tried others (e.g. program=xelatex), but to no avail.

`latexmk` describes its commands as follows:

```
$ latexmk -commands xelatex job
Commands used by latexmk:
   To run latex, I use "latex %O %S"
   To run pdflatex, I use "pdflatex %O %S"
   ...
```

There doesn't appear bo be any logical mechanism for selecting a tex program from the command line, and it's not clear from the source how one would do this, either.

I've also looked at[`rubber`](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~beffara/soft/rubber/), but it doesn't seem to work either.

I appreciate any insight you may be able to provide.

Brian

Comment: Which version of latexmk are you using?  Besiedes the original, there is the Texshop version of latexmk maintained by Herbert Schulz, or the Texlive default version by John Collins? Look at the output to latexmk -v to see which. Only the Texshop version comes packaged with xelatexmk and recognises !TEX directives; with the jcc version you will have to write an RC file to invoke xelatex and how to handle xdv files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's my **quick fix**, so that `latexmk` works with XeLaTeX:
Add

```
`elsif (/^-xelatex$/) { $pdf_mode = 1; $pdflatex = 'xelatex %O %S'; $pdf_previewer =
'start evince %O %S';}`
```

above (or near) the line

```
`elsif (/^-pdf$/) { $pdf_mode = 1; }`
```

.

Then you can call `latexmk -xelatex file.tex`. Works, but I didn't test it extensively. Should work similarly with `lualatex`.

Comment: I'll add an -xelatex option to latexmk in the next version (4.31).  This will work like the modification given here (except for the setting of the previewer to evince).

Comment: Notably, as of version 4.24, you can get this same effect by doing `latexmk -pdflatex='xelatex %O %S' -pdf [...]` instead of modifying the latexmk script. It's a bit verbose, but it gets the job done. If/when a flag is added, I'd prefer it if were based on a variable $xelatex. That way we can define the variable in ~/.latexmkrc in order to pass flags etc like we do now with $latex and $pdflatex.

Answer (score 19):

```
latexmk -v
Latexmk, John Collins, 16 January 2010. Version 4.13a
```

I put

```
$pdflatex = 'xelatex --shell-escape %O %S';
```

in my .latexmkrc file. This is a workaround, of course. But it works for me when I call

```
latexmk -pvc -pdf MyXetexFile
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$ latexmk -v
Latexmk, John Collins, 27 July 2010. Version 4.18
```

I run with the command:

```
latexmk -pdf -e '$pdflatex=q/xelatex %O %S/' foo.tex
```

which is basically the same as the answers from andre-r and Kay, but only from the command-line.

Answer (score 9):

In version: 4.65 (18 June 2019), there is a difference between using the `-xelatex` option and setting `-pdflatex` as suggested by one of the comments.

### Option 1: -xelatex

```sh
$ latexmk -xelatex file.tex
```

With the `-xelatex` option, or the `-pdfxe` option, the tex file is first typeset to an `xdv` ([extended DVI](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-dvi)) file.  Then, `xdvipdfmx` is called to convert the `xdv` file to a `pdf` file.

In `latexmk`, `$xelatex_default_switches` is set to `-no-pdf` (line 395) to have `xelatex` produce an `xdv` file instead of the default PDF file.

Hence the `-xelatex` option is equivalent to:

```sh
$ xelatex -no-pdf file.tex  # called one or more times to produce file.xdv
$ xdvipdfmx file.xdv        # called only once in the end
```

### Option 2: -pdflatex=xelatex

A second option is to set `pdflatex` as follows along with turning on the `-pdf` option:

```sh
# %O is a substitution for options and %S is for source file
$ latexmk -pdflatex='xelatex %O %S' -pdf file.tex
```

In this approach, `xelatex` is used to generate the PDF file directly, without generating an intermediate output file.  Note that, today, `xelatex` first generates an `xdv` stream and internally pipes it to `xdvipdfmx` to produce a PDF file.

Hence this approach is equivalent to:

```sh
$ xelatex file.tex     # called one or more times to produce file.pdf
```

---

Updated 2019.08.31 from `user36296`'s comment.

Comment: In the second option the intermediate file will be generated internally and converted to pdf on every run. Therefore this option is slightly slower than the first option where the conversion to pdf is only done once in the end

Answer (score 7):

`latexmk --xelatex job.tex`
Now the argument is passable in this simple form.